# Настройка 404 ошибки в php

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404

Сейчас на сайте, если происходит запрос к несуществующей статье или разделу текстом вывозится, что такой статьи или раздела не существует, но сервер отдает 200.
Как настроить для таких страниц 404 ошибку?
Нагуглить получилось такую конструкцию

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
exit(); 
?>
```

Но я не понимаю, куда ее добавить нужно и как использовать.
Запрос к `mysql` выглядит так

```
<?php
 function get_articles($link){
   $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE alias_cat ="'.$_GET['id_cat'].'" AND alias ="'.$_GET['id'].'"';
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   $articles= array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $articles[] = $row;
   }
   return $articles;
 }
?>
```

кусок `php` код на странице статьи так:

```
<?php
   $articles = get_articles($link);
 ?>
 <?php if (count($articles) ===0 ) : ?>
   <h1 class="h1">Страница не найдена</h1>
 <?php else: ?>
 <?php foreach($articles as $article): ?>
   <h1 class="h1"><?=$article['name']?></h1>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

При попытке добавить конструкцию в любой участок кода выдает ошибку о том, что header уже задан. Знаю, что добавлять нужно в самое начало, но ведь сначала нужно проверить существует или нет страница, а для этого подключиться к базе. Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: по куску кода понятно почему работает именно так, но помочь без файла который изначально формирует страницу не представляется возможным, т.к. это не типовая cms.

Answer (score 1):

Проверка должна быть до вывода страницы, работа скрипта должна прерываться, иначе выведет остаток информации.

```
<?php
    if(count($articles) === 0)
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        include("upload/404.php");
        die();
    }    
?>
```

Строка include("upload/404.php"); подгружает нужную страницу для показа.

Переопределить заголовок уже отданной страницы достаточно сложно, но как альтернативный вариант быстро можно поставить запрет индекса.

Comment: Задаю сразу после тега <html>, все равно выдает ошибку "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at functions.php:15)" причем 15-ая строка в файле functions.php вообще не имеет отношения к этой странице и никакой header там не задается

Comment: headers должны устанавливаться ДО отправки контента пользователю. Соответсвтвенно - и до тэга <html>

Comment: Ошибка все равно остается. Попробовал оставить include("upload/404.php");
        die();  
а менять header в файле 404.php, все равно та же ошибка, хотя в этом файле смена заголовка вообще первой строкой

Comment: <?php echo '12345' ?>, вот тоже самое происходит со статьей, просто её вывод в уже сформированной странице. Проверка должна быть раньше чем страница сформирована, в теории в index.php или том файле который отвечает за вывод статьи, вначале проверяем есть в базе или нет.

Comment: @Al_nav А пока найдём пути решения этой проблемы. Чаще всего такие ситуации происходят из-за использования BOM. BOM - это 2 или 3 невидимых символа в начале файла. Эти символы указывают на то, какая используется кодировка. Многие текстовые редакторы по умолчанию добавляют BOM ко всем файлам юникодовской кодировкой (например UTF-8). Например, в Notepad++... там можно открыть файл и в меню "Кодировки" и выбрать "Преобразовать в UTF-8 без BOM". А также внимательно посмотрите что бы перед header не было не каких echo и выводов любой информации